# Possible to use/lay out a Compose view in an Activity written in Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Google gives the following example of how to use a ComposeView in XML and inflate it in a fragment.

```
class ExampleFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_example, container, false
        ).apply {
            findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.compose_view).setContent {
                // In Compose world
                MaterialTheme {
                    Text("Hello Compose!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have an activity written in java, not kotlin.  Is it possible to use setContent from a Java activity?  If so I am struggling with the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

First you should create a subclass of `AbstractComposeView`:

```kotlin
class MyComposeView
@JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null) :
    AbstractComposeView(context, attrs) {
    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        YourComposableFunction()
    }
}
```

and then set this view as Activity content...

```java
public class MyJavaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyComposeView(this));
    }
}
```

You can also declare your view in any layout file...

```xml
<com.example.MyComposeView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and call `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file)` as usual.

Comment: This overrides the entire content view.  What if I am using a ComposeView tag in xml as a partial compose in an existing layout file?

Comment: No problem at all... you can use this custom view in your XML layout file as usual... <your.app.package.MyComposeView... />

Comment: @nglauber @lostintranslation Creating an `AbstractComposeView` is redundant here , we can simply wrap up a kotlin object / class and render the content underneath. (Thought the question mostly asked about the syntax from java class.)

}


However i can only find creating `AbstractComposeView` or `ComposeView` useful from `Fragment` and **NOT** `Activity` 
( or section of an activity where we want to render a compsable UI )

Comment: I see, but using your approach you can't use your composable in a XML layout file. As you can see in the first comment of this answer, he wants to put the composable in a layout XML file.

Comment: Does the first line of the question ask for a solution involving any XML layout ? Not sure though.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of creating an `AbstractComposeView` , you can simply wrap up a kotlin function and pass on the activity instance and set the content.
For example:

```
object ComposeContent {
    fun setContentFromJavaActivity(activity: AppCompatActivity) {
        activity.setContent {
            // Your composable content goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Activity `onCreate(..)` :-

```
public class MyJavaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ComposeContent.INSTANCE.setContentFromJavaActivity(this);
    }
}
```

(Creating instance of `AbstractComposeView` or `ComposeView` comes handy only when we want to render a section of an Activity with a compose UI (or in a `Fragment`))

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need the AbstractComposeView. I was able to do this just with the following:

Add ComposeView to your layout.xml just as you would any other View:

```
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
    android:id="@+id/compose_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Create a new kt file, for example ComposeFunctions.kt that has a function to set the content to the ComposeView:

```
@file:JvmName("ComposeFunctions")

package (your package goes here)

fun setContent(composeView: ComposeView) {
    composeView.setContent { composable kt function goes here }
}
```

Now from your java Activity/Fragment

```
ComposeView composeView = view.findViewById(R.id.compose_view);
ComposeFunctions.setContent(composeView);
```

I have used this successfully on WearOS for androidx.wear.compose.material.TimeText:

```
composeView.setContent { TimeText() }
```

Answer (score 0):

To manage it from a single place, we can manage it with the help of a manager in both Kotlin and Java.

object ComposeViewManager {

```
fun setComposableContent(
    composeView: ComposeView,
    content: ComposableProvider,
) {
    composeView.apply {
        setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
        setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                content.ProvideComposableContent()
            }
        }
    }
}

fun setComposableContentForKotlin(
    composeView: ComposeView,
    content: @Composable ComposableProvider.() -> Unit,
) {
    composeView.apply {
        setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
        setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                ComposableProviderImpl().content()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

In my article where I explain in detail how to use Compose View in Java and Kotlin: [*What is ComposeView and How to Use in Kotlin and Java codes?*](https://medium.com/@burockcan2309/what-is-composeview-and-how-to-use-in-kotlin-and-java-codes-dac48e918777)

With clean architecture