# How to load jetpack compose from java activity

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, customdialog

How to load jetpack compose from java activity?

I have java activity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

but on the button click I want to open @Composable function.

I'm calling it from java via

```
fun setContent(activity: AppCompatActivity){
        activity.setContent {
                CustomDialog() // contains Dialog
        }
    }
```

But this composable function destroy my previous view.

How can I open this custom dialog on the previous view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found only such solution:

```
class JetPackDialog() : DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                JetPackDialogView()
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in a related post. Took me hours of searching to find it...
[Possible to use/lay out a Compose view in an Activity written in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67423907/possible-to-use-lay-out-a-compose-view-in-an-activity-written-in-java/76612457#76612457?newreg=7e15da165ac149f2a61ff9685af9be59)

> You don't necessarily need the AbstractComposeView. I was able to do
> this just with the following:
>
> Add ComposeView to your layout.xml just as you would any other View:

```
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
     android:id="@+id/compose_view"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

> Create a new kt file, for example ComposeFunctions.kt that has a function to set the content to
> the ComposeView:

```
@file:JvmName("ComposeFunctions")
 
 package (your package goes here)
 
 fun setContent(composeView: ComposeView) {
     composeView.setContent { composable kt function goes here } }
```

> Now from your java Activity/Fragment

```
ComposeView composeView = view.findViewById(R.id.compose_view);
 ComposeFunctions.setContent(composeView);
```

> I have used this
> successfully on WearOS for androidx.wear.compose.material.TimeText:
>
> composeView.setContent { TimeText() }